# Gradle task to load files from Jar

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

I use vendor library to generate Java sources from an Xml. This source xml imports other xml which exists in some jar file. I know the coordinates of this Jar file. The vendor library is a blackbox to me but I know that it uses ThreadContextClassLoader to load the imports from a jar. However, it fails because it cannot find the imported xmls from the classpath/jars.

What is the gradle way of accomplishing this?

```
// body of gradle task
@TaskInput
void execute(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
   inputs.outOfDate { changes ->
       // CodeGenerator is the vendor library
       CodeGenerator generator = new CodeGenerator();
       // call some setter methods to set the inputs.
       //
       generators.setXml(file("<path/to/the-file"))
       generator.generate();
   } 
}
```

Comment: maybe you can paste how you currently invoke the vendor library from gradle. Then maybe it's just a matter of adding the jar to the classpath of that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my other answer we have ascertained that there's no option to set the classloader for the `CodeGenerator`. So, the only option is to have the jar with the xml files loaded by the same classloader as the CodeGenerator`.

Option 1: Add the jar to the buildscript classpath in a `buildscript { ... }` block

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.group:jar-with-xmls:1.0'
    }
}
```

Option 2: Add the jar to the buildscript classpath via `buildSrc/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.vendor:code-generator:1.0'
    runtime 'com.group:jar-with-xmls:1.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Option 1 worked for me. I am curious to know in what way Option 2 is different from Option 1.

Comment: You would use option 2 if you wanted to compile extra tasks etc in `buildSrc/src/main/java`

Answer (score 1):

Does the `CodeGenerator` have a `setClassloader(Classloader)` method? You could likely use a `Configuration` and a `URLClassloader`. Eg:

```
configurations {
   codeGenerator
}
dependencies {
   codeGenerator 'foo:bar:1.0'
   codeGenerator 'baz:biff:2.0'
}
task generateCode {
    inputs.files configurations.codeGenerator
    outputs.dir "$buildDir/codeGenerator"
    doLast {
        URL[] urls = configurations.codeGenerator.files.collect { it.toUri().toUrl() }
        Classloader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls, null)
        CodeGenerator generator = new CodeGenerator()
        generator.setClassLoader(cl)
        ...
        generator.generateTo("$buildDir/codeGenerator")
    }
}
```

See a similar concept [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164073/1089967)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no setter method to set URLClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

jar files are zip archives. You can open them as zipfiles using java.util.zip classes. In gradle, you might want to use ziptree to extract, as explained here:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.jp/2012/06/gradle-goodness-unpacking-archive.html

Comment: I know how to get a ZipEntry. Problem is that I provide the name of xml to the library and thats it. The library itself parses the Xml and figures what other Xml to imports. I do not have mechanisms to get the names of the file to be loaded.